# pEntity already has a parent

Tags: android, andengine

I want attach sprites in different layers. I do this:

```
    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LAYERS; i++) {
        scene.attachChild(new Entity());
    }

            ...
            ...

    scene.attachChild(
            getSprite(),1);
```

LogCat gives out an error:

0

```
2-29 10:30:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(17018): java.lang.IllegalStateException: pEntity already has a parent!
```

Why so occurs? And how attach sprites in different layers?

Comment: this question is a tad vague at best - does the error occur on the new pEntity? or on the getSprite()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is saying that the entity you want to attach to scene already has another parent so either you have to detach it or you can clone the entity and then attach to scene each time

to detech the code is

```
entity.detachSelf();
```

and for clone it is simply

```
entity.clone();
```

Comment: why I can not use scene.detachChild(child)?

Comment: i haven't worked on this for a long time so i actually don't know about this. it may work. have you tried? if it's not working then what error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but then i solved it which sprite you want to attach first detach it by

entity.detachself();

then attach that child

entity.attachChild();